# PHP: List Links related to a file name

Tags: php

I have a Repository, that looks like this

[image: directory]

In my debs/Index.PHP i have a PHP scripts to list the .deb files inside debs folder, that's my script:

```
<?PHP
#  directory
$directory = dir("./");

# Extension Filter, comment to disable:
 $allowed_ext = array(".deb", ".txt", ".ext", ".ext", ".ext", ".ext"); 


$do_link = TRUE; 
$sort_what = 0; //0:y name; 1: by size; 2:by date
$sort_how = 0; //0: ASCENDING;    1:DESCENDING


# # #
function dir_list($dir){ 
    $i=0; 
    $dl = array(); 
    if ($hd = opendir($dir))    { 
        while ($sz = readdir($hd)) {  
            if (preg_match("/^\./",$sz)==0) $dl[] = $sz;$i.=1;  
        } 
    closedir($hd); 
    } 
    asort($dl); 
    return $dl; 
} 
if ($sort_how == 0) { 
    function compare0($x, $y) {  
        if ( $x[0] == $y[0] ) return 0;  
        else if ( $x[0] < $y[0] ) return -1;  
        else return 1;  
    }  
    function compare1($x, $y) {  
        if ( $x[1] == $y[1] ) return 0;  
        else if ( $x[1] < $y[1] ) return -1;  
        else return 1;  
    }  
    function compare2($x, $y) {  
        if ( $x[2] == $y[2] ) return 0;  
        else if ( $x[2] < $y[2] ) return -1;  
        else return 1;  
    }  
}else{ 
    function compare0($x, $y) {  
        if ( $x[0] == $y[0] ) return 0;  
        else if ( $x[0] < $y[0] ) return 1;  
        else return -1;  
    }  
    function compare1($x, $y) {  
        if ( $x[1] == $y[1] ) return 0;  
        else if ( $x[1] < $y[1] ) return 1;  
        else return -1;  
    }  
    function compare2($x, $y) {  
        if ( $x[2] == $y[2] ) return 0;  
        else if ( $x[2] < $y[2] ) return 1;  
        else return -1;  
    }  

} 

################################################## 
#    We get the information here 
################################################## 

$i = 0; 
while($file=$directory->read()) { 
    $file = strtolower($file);
    $ext = strrchr($file, '.');
    if (isset($allowed_ext) && (!in_array($ext,$allowed_ext)))
        {
            // dump 
        }
    else { 
        $temp_info = stat($file); 
        $new_array[$i][0] = $file; 
        $new_array[$i][1] = $temp_info[7]; 
        $new_array[$i][2] = $temp_info[9]; 
        $new_array[$i][3] = date("F d, Y", $new_array[$i][2]); 
        $i = $i + 1; 
        } 
} 
$directory->close(); 

################################################## 
# We sort the information here 
################################################# 

switch ($sort_what) { 
    case 0: 
            usort($new_array, "compare0"); 
    break; 
    case 1: 
            usort($new_array, "compare1"); 
    break; 
    case 2: 
            usort($new_array, "compare2"); 
    break; 
} 

############################################################### 
#    We display the infomation here 
############################################################### 

$i2 = count($new_array); 
$i = 0; 
echo "<table class='CSSTableGenerator'> 
                <tr> 
                    <td width=355>File name (Download)</td> 
                    <td align=center width=70>File Size</td> 
                    <td align=center width=100>Last Modified</td> 
                </tr>"; 
for ($i=0;$i<$i2;$i++) { 
    if (!$do_link) { 
        $line = "<tr><td>" .  
                        $new_array[$i][0] .  
                        "</td><td>" .  
                        number_format(($new_array[$i][1]/1024)) .  
                        " KB"; 
        $line = $line  . "</td><td>" . $new_array[$i][3] . "</td></tr>"; 
    }else{ 
        $line = '<tr><td align=left ><A class="ex1" HREF="' .   
                        $new_array[$i][0] . '">' .  
                        $new_array[$i][0] .  
                        "</A></td><td>"; 
        $line = $line . number_format(($new_array[$i][1]/1024)) .  
                        " KB"  . "</td><td>" .  
                        $new_array[$i][3] . "</td></tr>"; 
    } 
    echo $line; 
} 
echo "</table>"; 
?>
```

The output of the scripts is:

[image: output]

So, What i want to do is to add a new column, which will contain a link to the Depiction page of the deb if it exists. The page will be in Depiction/"package-name"/index.php

Maybe we can use the beginning of the deb name "com.name.app1" to get the depiction file for it.

The new output would look like that:

[image: output2]

I would appreciate if someone can help me achieve this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to specify the url for the link as one folder up relative to the current path (`../`), then take the first x number of characters of the file name you already have in your `$new_array` counted from `com.name.app1` as you stated:

```
if (!$do_link) { 
    $line = "<tr><td>" . $new_array[$i][0];
    $line .= '</td><td><a href="' . '../Depiction/' . substr($new_array[$i][0], 0, strlen("com.name.app1")) . '/index.php">Depiction</a>';
    $line .= "</td><td>" . number_format(($new_array[$i][1]/1024)) . " KB"; 
    $line .= "</td><td>" . $new_array[$i][3] . "</td></tr>"; 
}
```

**EDITED:** If the first section of your file doesn't always have a set number of characters, but it is always divided by an underscore (`_`) for example (you will have to specify a specific pattern, the system cannot guess it for you), you could change that portion of the code like this:

```
substr($new_array[$i][0], 0, strpos($new_array[$i][0], "_"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it actually works but i have one problem, the name of the app in "com.name.app1" is not always app1 sometimes its larger than 4 chars, it can be app123 or any other name, i just set an example app1 to make it easier, so with the code you gave me it just takes xxx.xxxx.xxxx if the name is shorter or longer it doesn't work, how can i fix that? Thanks!

Comment: I am getting an error about strpros function: `Warning: strpos() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given` i think strpros should be something like this `strpos(string,find,start)`

Answer (score 0):

If it is not important to have an extra column for the link, then you can set the $do_link to true. If you set $do_link to true then the filename will become clickable.

If you want to have the extra column for the download then change the following line:

```
        $line = "<tr><td>" .  
                    $new_array[$i][0] .  
                    "</td><td>" .  
                    number_format(($new_array[$i][1]/1024)) .  
                    " KB";
```

into

```
    $line = "<tr><td>" . $new_array[$i][0] .  "</td>".
         '<a class="ex1" href="' .$new_array[$i][0] . '">Depiction</a></td>'.
         "<td>" . number_format(($new_array[$i][1]/1024)) .  " KB";
```

The table only lists existing files, so all files will be downloadable.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, i am not trying to add a download link, but i want to add a new column for the description page for the same deb file which is located in the depiction folder, each deb has its own depiction